# dependence between radiobutton and dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code

```
protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (RadioButton1.Checked)
    {
        RadioButton2.Checked = false;
        DropDownList1.Enabled = true;
    }
    if (!RadioButton1.Checked)
    {
        RadioButton2.Checked = true;
    }

}
protected void RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (RadioButton2.Checked)
    {
        RadioButton1.Checked = false;
        DropDownList1.Enabled = false;
    }
    if (!RadioButton1.Checked)
    {
        RadioButton1.Checked = true;
    }
}
<asp:DropDownList   ID="DropDownList1"  runat="server" DataSourceID="BookStore" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name"  Height="51px" Width="300px" DataMember="DefaultView">

</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="BookStore" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BookStoreConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Name] FROM [Books] ORDER BY [Name]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<p>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Checked="True" GroupName="1" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged" />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" GroupName="1" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton2_CheckedChanged" />

</p>
```

But when I click radiobuttons, dropdownlist is alwais enabled. When I write this functions in webforms app(not asp.net) its working correct.What could be the reason of this uncorrect working?

Comment: have you set autopostback property of radio buttons are true?

Comment: @Mysterio11 thanks. autopostback property fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

May be problem in `RadioButton2_CheckedChanged` event in second if condition, this should check `RadioButton2.Checked` not `RadioButton1.Checked`. instead of checking this condition if you put `else` still this will work no need to check again.

```
if (!RadioButton2.Checked)
{
    RadioButton1.Checked = true;
}
```

Comment: @JaidipJ DropDownList1 still enabled when RadioButton2.Checked

Comment: In pageLoad event did you check is their any code to set DropDownList1.Enable property?

Comment: autopostback property fix my problem

Comment: Great I thought some thing went wrong in Page load event and thats correct